# "Invalid 2nd argument" when using INTNX in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a dataset and there is a variable called date. It looks like "31MAY13:00:00:00" and its datatype is date. Now I want to create a new variable such that it is the first day of the corresponding month. So for "31MAY13:00:00:00", it will give me "01MAY13:00:00:00". Here's my code:

```
DATA newdata;
SET olddata;
newvariable = INTNX('month',olddate,0,"B");
RUN;
```

The log says: Argument 2 to function INTNX is invalid. It's been a while working with SAS for me. Any idea? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your value is a datetime, not a date. You need to add `dt` to the front of the interval like this to increment a datetime value:

```
DATA newdata;
SET olddata;
newvariable = INTNX('dtmonth',olddate,0,"B");
RUN;
```

Comment: How could I have forgotten that! Thank you very much, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Besides what @Dwal has suggested you could use "datepart" function to extract date and could use the same formula which you had been using.

```
newvariable = INTNX('month',datepart(olddate),0,"B");
```

Comment: Actually after I opened the Property window, it says "Type:Numeric, Group:Date, Format:DATETIME18.". What should I do now?

Comment: I know, it's really weird. I used input wizard to input my data, and I chose the datatype as "datetime". Also I'm using SAS Enterprise Guide, could that be the problem?

Comment: `"31MAY13:12:00:00"d` is not equal to `"31MAY13:12:00:00"dt`. They are different values. Datetime values require datetime intervals (e.g. `dtmonth`) in this type of function.